# AngularJs - Manipulate Template inside Link Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, templates

I have a directive that looks something like this

```
    interface IMyDirectiveScope extends ng.IScope {

        emptyOption: boolean;
        foo: boolean;
    }

    class MyDirective implements IMyDirective {

        require: string = 'ngModel';
        restrict: string = "AE";
        replace: boolean = true;
        transclude: boolean = true;

        scope = {
            foo: '=',

        };
        template: string = '<select class="something" ng-options="something"></select>';


    link = ($scope: IMyDirectiveScope , $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl: ng.INgModelController) => {

        $scope.emptyOption = !(<any>$attrs).required;

 if ($scope.emptyOption) {
        var el = angular.element(this.template);
        var elementHtml = this.$compile('<option value="">-</option>')($scope);
        angular.element(el).append(elementHtml);
    }
};
```

My options are created dynamically inside link function, and if my element does not required an option, i want to add an empty option, this is why i'm trying to append this `<option>` element, but i can't find a way to append it to the template element. The way i'm doing now, the var el gets the way i want.

**Update:** i have searched a little more, i have found that for this kind of directive, where i use `replace` and `transclude`, to manipulate i need the `tranclude function` on link, although i couldn't understand how, any help? i'm on the right track? cause `compile` does nothing for me, i've tried already

Comment: `var el = angular.element($element);` or just `var el = $element`, you can try one of these two.

Comment: yes, but that is not my problem, because using either $element, or this.template i get the same result